# asp.net in OpenFileDialog

Tags: asp.net, debugging, openfiledialog

I am creating a web server through asp.net.
The source works well in debug mode.
However, after posting to iis, if you go through the source, you will get the error 'HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable' after about 20 seconds.
I am confident that there is an error in the OpenFileDialog section.
In the past, this code worked well after posting. I do not know what has been modified since then.

Thanks in advance for your help.

.js code

```
            action: function (e, dt, node, config) {
                $.ajax({
                    "url": "/api/Member/ExcelRead",
                    "type": "POST",
                    "datatype": 'json',
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data === 'OK') {
                            alert("성공");
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (response, state, errorCode) {
                        alert("실패");
                    }

                });
```

.cs

```
public class MemberController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public string ExcelRead()
    {

        ExcelHelper helper = new ExcelHelper();
        Thread th = new Thread(helper.ReadExcelData);

        th.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);

        th.Start();
        th.Join();
        if (helper.data == null)
            return ("NO");


        return ("OK");

    }
}


    public void ReadExcelData()
    {
        IsRun = false;
        OpenFileDialog openFile = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFile.DefaultExt = "xlsx";
        openFile.Filter = "Excel Files(*.xlsx)|*.xlsx";
        DialogResult dresult = openFile.ShowDialog();
        if (dresult != DialogResult.OK)
        {
            return;
        }
        if (openFile.FileNames.Length > 0)
        {
            foreach (string filename in openFile.FileNames)
            {
                //this.textBox1.Text = filename;
            }
        }
     }
```

Comment: `OpenFileDialog` is in the `System.Windows.Forms` namespace, just sayin'.

Comment: I already added it. It works well in debugging mode.

Comment: You are missing the point. OpenFileDialog is a WinForm functionality. It is not meant for websites.

Comment: In my memory this seems to have worked well. So what should I do?

Comment: Use Modals, like https://jqueryui.com/dialog/